# Is there any way to get the id of clicked value and send it to another page using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem getting the attribute value of clicked a href tag, happens when I click this href tag yes the value is showing, but when my browser send me to the peoplegallery_album the id now turning to null, I though my browser refresh that's why the value is turning to null. so happens the response shows nothing. `<a href="/peoplegallery_album/'+gallery_id+'" class="clicked_albums" data-id='+gallery_id+' style="color:black; font-weight: 500;">'+gallery_content_title+'</a>\`

**Question: Why my first clicked item the value is showing then after my browser send me to the second page i didn't get any response, is it because my browser refresh?.**

**I will show you the sample the clicked item return with value.**
[image: Showing result]

**Now i created api to list of all items in the peoplegallery album with the id...**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $(document).on('click','.clicked_albums',function(e) {

        var album_id= $(this).data('id'); 
        alert(album_id);

        $.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost:8000/api/peoplegallery_album/'+ album_id,
            type:'get',
            data: {id: album_id},
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            processData: true,
            success:function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error:function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

    }); 
});
```

**So it look like this i didn't get any response after browser send me to the other page.**
[image]

Comment: You have too many redirects. Like <a> tag will redirect you to page, but you make also ajax call. I guess it lost as browser refresh page. So put your click event to <div>. Also I am not sure about your url in Get. You putting also data param there and url ends with you id...decide what you want to use

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage instead of ajax

```js
//This page

function a(e)
{
var t=e.getAttribute('id');
localStorage.setItem('id',t);
}

//Other page

var k=localStorage.getItem('id');

//for deleting

function b()
{
localStorage.removeItem('id');
}
```

```html
<a id="23" onclick="a(this)" href="#">This had id 23</a>
<a id="23" onclick="b()" href="#">delete localstorage</a>
```

Comment: yes the first think i need to use storage. but is there way beside of that?

Comment: You have to use cookies which essentially are storage only, besides that you have to use a server

Comment: Hi @Ashay, how to remove the storage if the user click the back of browser?

Comment: Use  `window.localStorage.removeItem('id');`

Comment: how you will condition it, if user wanted to change item clicked,

Comment: Check the edits. It will delete it when the other link is clicked

Comment: Ashay how to put the key value to the url, because i can't get the response url:'http://localhost:8000/api/peoplegallery_album/'+ k

Comment: `window.location="your_url"+id`

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour of the link element. It takes you to the URL that is specified in the 'href' attribute.

If you want to prevent the location change add

```
e.preventDefault()
```

before

```
var album_id= $(this).data('id');
```

**The right way to resolve data is to do it on the initial load of the page.**

It could be achieved in the next way:

- Check the id in the URL on the initial load.
- If ID is present then make the API request with it.
- If ID is absent do nothing.

Every time when you click on the link your page would be refreshed and the cycle will repeat.